# Eclipse and emacs+ : C-x 0 and C-x 2 does not work - C-x 1 and C-x 3 works

Tags: eclipse

I try to use [Emacs+](http://www.mulgasoft.com/) plugin for Eclipse. There is four ways to split windows :

- C-x 0 - removes current window
  (**does not work)**
- C-x 1 - show only the current windows (it works)
- C-x 2 - split horizontally (**does not work**)
- C-x 3 - split vertically (it works)

I have an azerty keyboard and if I want to write a number, I have to push "Shift + < number >". If I use the qwerty layout, there is no problem because I don't have to push "shift" to write a number.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the keys mapping in Preferences? (settings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone's keybindings are different.  In emacs you can say that `C-x2` is often bound to a particular function, but it is not the case that it always is bound in that way.  In your situation it is more complicated because of the different keyboard.

You may find it helpful to use `describe-key` to tell you about the keystrokes you are using. It will tell you about a particular key combination, as you type it, including what function is bound to it, if any. I personally have `describe-key` bound to `C-h k`.

There is the converse, `describe-function` (bound to `C-h f` for me), which will tell you about a function whose name you provide, including what keys it is bound to.  Using these may help you diagnose.

For me, `C-x 2` runs the command `split-window-vertically` and  `C-x 3` runs the command `split-window-horizontally`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the keybindings and was successfull.

In my environment I use

- Eclipse 3
- Emacs+ 3.6.0
- Windows 7

Hope this is any help for you.

But perhaps you should check the key settings in Eclipse. Look for *Preferences->General->Keys*
Search for *split window* and you will see your settings in Eclipse.